# MYSQL query not regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-update, crud

I have written the following query where i want to select rows that don't carry any of `abc` or `cde` and `bcg`.

In the output, I am still getting rows with `abc` or `cde` and `bcg`.

```
select * from table where column1 not regexp 'abc|cde|bcg';
```

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Please provide an example.

Comment: In my output i am still able to see `AB220BCGHDA1229`

Comment: @all_technie . . . That does not contain "abc", "cde", or "bcg".

Comment: it has `BCG` in the middle

Comment: Perhaps you have a case sensitive collation.  The code works as you want in rextester:  http://rextester.com/WYNGSY53274.

Comment: Do you mean (abc OR cde) AND bcg?  Or do you mean abc OR (cde AND bcg)?

Comment: Give about 10 examples -- specify which ones you want.

Comment: `SELECT 'AB220BCGHDA1229' not regexp 'abc|cde|bcg';` --> 0.  Why are you seeing it??

Comment: You mention "middle" -- are you trying to avoid the _entire_ string being any of those??